# Promise reject with thenable

Tags: javascript

```
const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        rej(Promise.resolve('resolved'))
    },1000)
})

promise.catch(data => {
    return data;
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data) //prints 'resolved' only if i return the value in catch otherwise undefined
})



const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        res(Promise.reject('rejected'))
    },1000)
})

promise.then(data => {
    //nothing
}).catch(data => {
    console.log(data) //prints 'rejected' even though am not returning any value in then
})
```

i know then block will be quit if we are not fulfilling or by rejecting the promise.
How Catch is handling the resolve(not fulfil yet)

can anyone explain this!
and also i can use thenable obj in first parameter (res method) not in second parameter i.e(rej method) what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

#### The first code snippet:

The promise that a `catch()` method will return, will be resolved with what you return in that `catch` callback. Since in the first case you return `data`, which is a resolved promise (thenable), the chained `then` callback will be executed, and print what the resolved promise resolved to, i.e. "resolved".

If instead you don't return anything in the `catch` callback, then you effectively let it return `undefined`. Again this will fulfil the promise that was returned by calling `catch()` with that `undefined` value, and so that is the value that will be printed in the `then` callback.

#### The second code snippet:

Here the `then()` callback is not executed, because `promise` is rejected -- even though `res` was called, it took the resolution from `Promise.reject()`. Promises that are rejected will not call any `then` callbacks (at least not the *first* callback passed to `then` -- one can define a second argument, that will act like a `catch` callback).

The promise that `then()` returns takes the same state as `promise`, and is thus also rejected. Therefore the chained `catch` callback is executed with the rejection reason as argument, which is the string "rejected".

So again, important here is that the `then` callback is *not* executed. Even if you would put a `console.log` in it, it would not get executed. It does not play a role.

### The difference between `res` and `rej` when it comes to thenables

When a promise is resolved (by calling `res`) with a thenable, then the promise will link its state with that thenable. If the thenable triggers a rejection, also the promise will reject. If it triggers a fulfilment, then also the promise will fulfil.

When a promise is rejected (by calling `rej`) with a thenable, then the promise will reject with the reason set to that thenable. There is no linking of state happening here like above. It really is different by design.

So in your first example, where you reject with a thenable, the `catch` handler will get the thenable as argument, not "resolved". But then it returns that thenable, and then the state-linking happens again: the promise returned by `catch` will link its state with the thenable. And so the chained `then` callback will get the string value "resolved", not the thenable.

Comment: and also if i reject a promise in first code snippent am getting warning?? is this because i cannot reject a promise that is  already rejected??

Answer (score 0):

That's a very confusing zone for anyone who is trying out promises for the first time. I have added comments to the same code which you have already posted. Hope it helps

```
const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // Here Promise.resolve returns a new Promise that is rejected by the promise created above.
        rej(Promise.resolve('resolved'))
    },1000)
})

// now promise has a rejected promise whose rejection returns a value of a promise which gets resolved.
promise.catch(data => {
    return data;
}).then(data => {
    // so here the data that we get is the value returned by Promise.resolve('resolved') i.e., a string that is having a value 'resolved'
    console.log(data);
})



const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // Here Promise.reject returns a new Promise that is resolved by the promise created above.
        res(Promise.reject('rejected'))
    },1000)
})

// Now the promise is actually resolves a rejected value.
// so it automatically goes to catch.
promise.then(data => { // here data is a promise rejection
// so it directly goes to the catch block
}).catch(data => {
    // now catch holds the data rejected by  `Promise.reject('rejected')`
    // so data will be 'rejected'
    console.log(data);
})
```